# How to create Mobile Application of Magento 2 Native?

Tags: magento2, api, frontend, rest-api, application

- How to create Mobile Application of Magento Native ?
- Using Magento 2 default REST API's how to create Front-end Magento 2
  application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this doc will help you get started: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/rest_front.html

If you can start building your own custom APIs for everything that your e-commerce app will have, you are going to be in a good spot.